# Android Studio cache the old Android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have old Android project with **com.premium_pets_store** bundle id

after running this command

```
git checkout -b anotherBranch
```

then changed the project bundle Id to **com.bytary**

then tried to run the project through Android Studio

it always fire error like this

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.premium_pets_store/com.bytary.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.premium_pets_store/com.bytary.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.premium_pets_store/com.bytary.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Certainly, I tried to search for that old bundle Id : **com.premium_pets_store**
it does not exist on the whole project,

so from where Android Studio read it? and why this issue ? I should removed the old project and replaced it with the new bundle id

Some common solutions I already tried like cleaning the project from Build > Clean Project

Android Studio version: Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Path 3

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear reason for that issue
however I tried multiple times to clean the project
and also remove **google-services.json** and add it again
then, the project worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).